# How to create custom collapsible Navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation

I'm trying to create the basic functionality for my custom NavBar that has a collapsible nav option when on small screen sizes.

Background: I've decided not  to use the default bootstrap nav classes because I heard you are limited to what you can do.( I want my navbar to have to two rows and to be able to place my content using bootstrap grid system)

Below is what I've tried so far but it has some issues with it and i'm sure there will be a better way to achieve this. maybe javascript or something?

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="nav">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="collapse-nav">
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-12 tx">
        <a href="#">LINK 1</a>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-12 tx">
        <a href="#">LINK 1</a>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-12 tx">
        <a href="#">LINK 1</a>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-12 tx">
        <a href="#">LINK 1</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<p id="collapse-btn">
  <a class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data- target="#collapse-nav">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span>
  </a>
</p>
```

CSS

```
#collapse-nav {
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
  #collapse-nav {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Comment: in bootstrap you are only limited by your imagination..if you want 2 rows for navigation use the navbar code twice and you will have 2 rows..you can style that anyway you want..when you have something handy why reinvent the wheel

Comment: ahhh i didn't think of that - Can you give an example?

Comment: @DeclanWatt something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/technotarek/ePGa9/